# How to show external pdf in html

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe

I have tried by using `iframe`:

```
  <iframe src="http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
```

But getting this warning:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf".
```

Is there any alternate option to show PDF file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementation of a PDF file in your HTML:

```
<embed src="http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"/>
```

Comment: Please try in your local system, as jsfiddle block sandboxes.Just Create a blank HTMl and in the body put this code: <embed src="http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"/>